# Websocket connection error on new Chrome version 56.0.2924.87

Tags: websocket, xmpp, strophe

Recently we observed that Websocket connection is failing only on latest Chrome version 56.0.2924.87

It is working is rest of the browsers(ff,ie,safari) and works fine in previous Chrome version 55

Below is the error that i see

**WebSocket connection to 'wss://abc.abcserver.com/ws-xmpp' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED**

Did anyone face similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue on dozens of PCs here.
Re-creating the users' Chrome profile has resolved the issue, but Google needs to fix this.